# Can't increase the virtual drive size any more?

Tags: vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vmware-vsphere

Please see attached picture, This is exchange server and I have 3 virtual hard drives, each of them can't not be increased any more, any idea why and how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The maximum disk size is typically limited by the amount of free space available on the datastore that holds the VM.

Check the free space on the datastore. If it is full try to move the VM to another datastore (that has more space) or move other VMs that are on the same datastore to somewhere else to free up space.

Comment: I has already done with the same approach. It is only a temp work around,  the datastore is full, need to create a new one ASAP.